# cron job with google calendar

Tags: php, cron, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a cron job running on a server, when I ssh into the server and folder, I can run the script with no problem. However, when the cron job runs it is looking for the token. Is there way to do this?

```
    function checkCalendar()
{
    $logFile = openLogFile("_Subscription.log");
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendarId = 'XXXX_CALENDAR_XXXX@group.calendar.google.com'; // Testing Calendat
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");//set timezone America/Lima
    $today = date("m-d-Y");
    $startofday = date("Y-m-d") . "T00:00:00-08:00";
    $endofday = date("Y-m-d") . "T23:59:59-08:00";
    $optParams = array('timeMax' => $endofday,
                      'timeMin' => $startofday);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
    writeLogMessage($logFile, "Subscriptions for {$today}\n");
   
    while(true) {
      foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
          writeLogMessage($logFile, "Customer -> " . $event->getSummary() . "\n");
          writeLogMessage($logFile, "DATA -> " . $event->getDescription() . "\n");
      }
     $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    closeLogFile($logFile);
    return("200");
}
```

`$calendarId` is the correct id it has been redacted from this post.

Here is the error:

```
Open the following link in your browser: 
accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=327785147494-fnorqnq2f8f2dejsrllf9dv6v4220sff.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&state&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&prompt=select_account consent 
Enter verification code: 
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid code in /home/customer/www/xxx-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/includes/google/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php:239 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/customer/www/xxx-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/includes/googleCalendar.php(47): Google\Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('') 
#1 /home/customer/www/xxx-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/includes/googleCalendar.php(104): getClient() 
#2 /home/customer/www/xxx-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/cron/CalendarRead.php(10): checkCalendar() 
#3 {main} 
thrown in /home/customer/www/xxx-consulting.com/public_html/PPLG/includes/google/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php on line 239
```

Comment: store the refresh token in a file and then load it from the file as needed

Comment: @DaImTo I do have a token stored in token.json in that same folder.

Comment: Please post the block containing line 239 of the Client.php so that we can have a look

Comment: ```  public function fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code)
  {
    if (strlen($code) == 0) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid code");
    }

    $auth = $this->getOAuth2Service();
    $auth->setCode($code);
    $auth->setRedirectUri($this->getRedirectUri());

    $httpHandler = HttpHandlerFactory::build($this->getHttpClient());
    $creds = $auth->fetchAuthToken($httpHandler);
    if ($creds && isset($creds['access_token'])) {
      $creds['created'] = time();
      $this->setAccessToken($creds);
    }

    return $creds;
  }
```

Comment: In the block, the code is contained in $code. Is this $code stored in the file token.json ? If this is true --- how do you read the file  (relative path or absolute path ?). If it is relative path, please change to absolute path and see the result

Comment: @KenLee doing that now

Comment: You shouldn't need code code is only for the first time the app is authorized.  please edit your question and put all your code there not in comments.